# Ethernet Passive Wire Tap

Tags: networking, ethernet

I was looking to make a passive Ethernet wire tap for my own home use just to see how it works. The only thing I'm not sure about is which pairs I need to passively tap? I've seen some pictures that use two taps and they use the green/green-white on one tap and orange/orange-white on the second tap.

I only want one tap because I only have a laptop and my desktop. So how would I go about doing this? I attached a picture that uses a two tap method to give an idea of what I'm looking to achieve.

[image]

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Mokubai it achieves the same thing any other wire tap does, enabling someone to listen in and monitor a connection.

Comment: This is completely against the cabling standard, and it may cause problems with communications since it introduces signal loss and impedance mismatches. The ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 standard specifically says that UTP cables cannot have splices or bridged taps because this will cause problems. Also, what you have will not work at all for 1000BASE-T (1 Gbps ethernet) since it uses all four pairs for both transmit and receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting experiment.

I have not conducted this experiment myself.
If I where to try it, I would look at this picture and come to the conclusion that

A "straight" cable:

Tap1, I would use RX(orange).

Tap2, I would use TX(green).

If it is a "crossover" cable:
Have look at the diagram.

[image]

Just as Jarmund points out, it is very likely you will get interference.

*Update
For those interested in this subject, I stumbled over Throwing Star Lan TAP. http://greatscottgadgets.com/throwingstar/

Comment: Thanks! I think based on the TX +/- and RX +/- pairs, I may only be able to listen to one conversation at a time. So I can either listen to what the host is transmitting, or what the router is transmitting but not both at the same time. I'll give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: Assuming it will work at all, you might be able to listen to traffic from both ends if you have two NIC's when you capture the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here, in effect, is attaching another NIC in parallell. I have seen hardware marketed as "ethernet splitters" based on the same concept, and they work, to some degree.

However, you should be aware that they greatly reduce the effectiveness of the cable, as the pairs are no longer properly twisted and are therefore more susceptible to interference.

Additionally, any NIC you plug in there as the "wiretap" should be passive only - Once it starts to transmit its own data on the wires, the wiretap can easily be detected, and depending on the setup between the original hosts, the NICs might start misbehaving.

Comment: I saw some devices that do this while searching for my solution. But I figured this way would be more fun and cheaper. I'm not wanting it for any real purpose so the reduced effectiveness would be ok with me. I'm just going to be sitting at my desktop with my laptop next to me seeing how the monitoring works :)

Answer (score 0):

Realize that UTP Ethernet is full duplex bidirectional.  That means that the packets going from the router to the modem are on a different pair of wires from the ones going from the modem to the router.  Therefore, if you are planning to eavesdrop with a single NIC, you can only listen to one of the directions at a time.  That's why the setup in the photo has two taps, to connect two NICs, one to listen to each side of the conversation.

Actually, if you don't mind the impact on the throughput and don't have a requirement to be undetectable, the simplest way to do what you want is to buy a small **hub** (not a switch), which repeats all packets heard on each port to every other port.  This means you have a more traditional *collision domain*, so you'll get a little less than half the total goodput between the original devices, but the added device gets to see all those packets (assuming it can do permissive mode).